# Android switching between textview, in drop down menu, and edittext on button click

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, baseadapter

**Situation:**

I have a spinner in my toolbar done by following [this guide](https://dabx.io/2015/01/02/material-design-spinner-toolbar-style-fix/). It looks like this:

[image: Spinner in toolbar]

**Problem:**

The user should be able to edit the name ("New" in this case) by clicking a "rename" button and then changing the name directly on the text shown (I'm guessing in the form of an EditText). How would I enable this functionality?

**Things I've tried:**

- ViewSwitcher: In my xml with the textview and an EditText inside the switcher. Then using viewSwitcher.showNext()/viewSwitcher.setDisplayedChild();
- setVisibility: set to visible/gone for the edittext/textview.

ToolbarSpinnerAdapter:

```
    public void rename() {
        switcher.showNext();
        editTextTitle.requestFocus();
        editTextTitle.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }
```

spinner_toolbar_actionbar:

```
<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/spinner_toolbar_actionbar_switcher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/spinner_triangle"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/spinner_toolbar_actionbar_edit_text_list_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/spinner_triangle"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp"/>
</ViewSwitcher>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround by just setting visibility on the spinner itself followed by making the edit text visible while maintaining the triangle drawable on the side.